# How to display image in mail header using wp_mail()

Tags: php, wordpress, image, email, html-email

How to display image in email header. I tried below, it in gmail it is not displaying the image. Please any one help me to resolve this.

```
    $to = $_REQUEST['userEmail'];
    $firstName = $_REQUEST['firstName'];
    $lastName = $_REQUEST['lastName'];
    $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
    $question = $_POST['message'];
    $subject = 'Test Email';
    $message = "<html><head><img src='http://192.168.1.157/Shop/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/image_nmae.png'/></head>"
            . "<body><h1>Visitor Information</h1>"
            . "<p>Visitor Information: Fist Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;".$firstName."&nbsp;&nbsp; Last Name:&nbsp;&nbsp; ".$lastName."</p>"
            . "<p>Email:&nbsp;&nbsp;".$email."</p><p>Question:&nbsp;&nbsp;".$question."</p></body></html>";
    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    $mailSend = wp_mail($to, $subject, $message,$headers);
```

Comment: have you tried my code? and does it helped?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the User Gmail account [settings](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/145919?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en), like in my Gmail account I had turned off image rendering, it ask my permission to load them or not.

Move the `<img>` tag inside the `<body>` tag, it is not a good practice to display image inside a head tag.

If it does't work, then write this in your `functions.php` file.

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_content_type' );
function set_content_type( $content_type ) {
    return 'text/html';
}
```